# set default font main window pyside

Tags: python, fonts, pyside

I am setting a simple text editor with PySide (python) and I would like to set the default font as, let's say, liberation mono. I am not interested in changing the font so I just need to set the font once for the main object. How would i do that?

this is the code I wrote to implement the main window:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initGUI()

    def initGUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("ScribblerSeq")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('./icon/appicon.png'))
        self.setGeometry(1200, 1800, 800, 600)
        self.statusLabel = QLabel('Showing Progress')
        self.CreateProgessBar()
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.center()
        self.SetupComponents()
        self.show()
```

thank you

Answer (score 4):

Using stylesheets:

```
main_window = MainWindow()

CURRENT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
style_path = os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'style', 'app.css')

# load and set stylesheet
with open(style_path, "r") as fh:
    main_window.setStyleSheet(fh.read())
```

app.css:

```
* { font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
```

Advantage of using external stylesheet files is that you can add easily change/add things later if you want.